# How to deploy Next.js with GraphQL backend on Zeit Now?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, next.js, vercel

I have an Next.js/Express/Apollo GraphQL app running fine on localhost.

I try to deploy it on Zeit Now, and the Next.js part works fine, but the GraphQL backend fails because `/graphql` route returns:

```
502: An error occurred with your deployment
Code: NO_STATUS_CODE_FROM_LAMBDA
```

My `now.json` looks like:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    { "src": "next.config.js", "use": "@now/next" },
    { "src": "server/server.js", "use": "@now/node" }
  ],
  "routes": [
    { "src": "/api/(.*)", "dest": "server/server.js" },
    { "src": "/graphql", "dest": "server/server.js" }
  ]
}
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a complete example of Next.js/Apollo GraphQL running both on Zeit Now (as serverless function/lambda) and Heroku (with an Express server):

**https://github.com/tomsoderlund/nextjs-pwa-graphql-sql-boilerplate**

[image: nextjs-pwa-graphql-sql-boilerplate]

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that error until I found on a solution on the Wes Bos slack channel.

The following worked for me, but it's possible you could be getting that error for a different reason.

I'm not sure why it works.

You can see it working [here](https://github.com/hmmChase/next-graphql-starter/tree/master/backend)

1. `cd backend`
2. Run `npm install graphql-import`
3. Update scripts in `package.json`:

```
"deploy": "prisma deploy --env-file variables.env&& npm run writeSchema",
"writeSchema": "node src/writeSchema.js"
```

> Note: For non windows users make sure to place space before `&&`

4. Create `src/writeSchema.js`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { importSchema } = require('graphql-import');
const text = importSchema("src/generated/prisma.graphql");
fs.writeFileSync("src/schema_prep.graphql", text)
```

5. Update `src/db.js`:

```
const db = new Prisma({
typeDefs: __dirname + "/schema_prep.graphql",
...
});
```

6. Update `src/createServer.js`:

```
return new GraphQLServer({
typeDefs: __dirname + '/schema.graphql',
...
});
```

7. Update `src/schema.graphql`:

```
# import * from './schema_prep.graphql'
```

8. Create `now.json`

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "name": "Project Name",
    "builds": [
        { "src": "src/index.js", "use": "@now/node-server" }
    ],
    "routes": [
        { "src": "/.*", "dest": "src/index.js" }
    ],
    "env": {
        "SOME_VARIABLE": "xxx",
        ...
    }
}
```

9. Run `npm run deploy` to initially create `schema_prep.graphql`.
10. Run `now`

---

Another reply said this:

> You should not mix graphql imports and js/ts imports. The syntax on the graphql file will be interpreted by graphql-import and will be ignored by ncc (the compiler which reads the __dirname stuff and move the file to the correct directory etc)
>   In my example 'schema_prep.graphql' is already preprocessed with the imports from the generated graphql file.

Hopefully this helps.