# How to have database driven Next.js app on ZEIT now

Tags: rest, routes, vercel

[GraphQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305509/how-to-deploy-next-js-with-graphql-backend-on-zeit-now) with ZEIT looks interesting, but for now I would simply like to create an API-driven Next.js app on ZEIT.

I have read through the docs and gotten a hello world example app running but haven't seen a full-fledged API-driven app and how it works.

- https://github.com/zeit/now-examples/blob/master/create-react-app/src/index.js
- https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/routes/
- https://reactresources.com/topics/zeit-now
- https://blog.bitsrc.io/react-production-deployment-part-2-now-c81657c700b7
- https://zeit.co/blog/now-dev

I would like to accomplish the following:

- serverless API
- render server-side next.js, fetching from an external data source (google bigquery)
- local dev workflow

I am a bit lost.

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "public": false,
  "builds": [
    { "src": "next.config.js", "use": "@now/next" },
    { "src": "server/server.js", "use": "@now/node" }
  ],
  "routes": [
    { "src": "/api/(.*)", "dest": "server/server.js" },
    { "src": ".*", "dest": "/index.html" }
  ]
}
```

I want instead of index.html it to be server-side rendered.

Comment: As you used `tag:rest` on this question in combination with GraphQL I just want to clarify that they are used for two different purposes. GraphQL is basically a SQL slang useful for certain RPC-esque APIs, REST on the other hand generalizes the interaction model used in the Web to decouple clients from servers and allow the former to evolve freely over time without the risk of breaking clients. It uses concepts as HATEOAS (linking) and teaching clients what to do (forms) to achieve this. Termed differently: do you use SQL or a similar slang to serf the Web?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you looking for an APi example or tutorial?